# add placeholder in views.Login in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i use django.contrib.auth.views import Login

but i want add css and placeholder to Login views

i use python3

Urls :

```
 url(r'^login$' ,  LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='Login' , kwargs={"authentication_form": LoginUser}),
```

form :

from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput

```
class LoginUser(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'style':'font-size : 20px;color:white','placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password' , 'style' : 'font-size : 20px;color:white'}))
```

this code don't work

i you can please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use folowing code:

```
class LoginUser(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'your_class', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'your_class', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```

I suggest to use css class and add class name to form field attr. You can also apply style, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not suggested to modify css attributes on the Django side, you can do it like this.

```py
class LoginUer(AuthenticationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # custom class attributes for all the fields, for example: bootstrap themes.
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class':'form-control'
                })

        # or you can modify the field attribute one by one.
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({
                 'class': 'whatever-class', 
                 'placeholder': 'your placeholder here'})
        # same for the password fields
```